# Get the pos_x and pos_y from screen from screen

Tags: vim, plugins, macvim

I would like to write a special plugin in Vim which open a custom app depending on the positions of the vim cursor.

Is any way to get the positions from the screen ?

Exemple case:
When I call my custom plugin ColorPicker, that's open a ColorPicker App centered on the cursor.
Screenshot: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6tc60GuFE4WbGxuaTV6OVlCSzg/edit

This is a very basic exemple but in I would like to be able to add powerfull gui feature to vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serious about creating a Vim plugin you should start by getting a bit closer with the help system. `:help functions` will give you a detailed list of all the available functions.

You are looking for `getpos('.')`, see `:help getpos()`.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to operate directly on the position, but on the word under the cursor; you can get that through `expand('<cword>')`.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. I just add some information to my post.

Comment: This is exactly what you asked: all the available functions are in `:h functions` which you should read. `getpos('.')` returns the line number and column of the cursor. If you also want to take into account the position of the GUI window you should use other functions: `:getwinposx()` and `getwinposy()` and extrapolate the cursor's exact position by checking for the presence of a menubar or toolbar, the font size, etc. Seriously, the doc is the first place to look at.

Comment: Ok I got it, I would look the help deeper next time ! Tank's :)